# Cant connect my LG G Pro 2 to adb on linux debain

Tags: android, linux, adb, lg

i am trying to connect my "LG G Pro 2" to adb on my Linux machine i have installed adb on Linux and i have also turned on the debug mode on my LG G Pro.
but  "sudo adb devices" cmd gives empty result.

```
    root@Unknown:~# sudo adb kill-server
    root@Unknown:~# sudo adb start-server
     * daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
     * daemon started successfully *
    root@Unknown:~# sudo adb devices
    List of devices attached
```

But "lsusb" command show my device is connected.

```
root@Unknown:~# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 1004:6300 LG Electronics, Inc. G2/Optimus Android Phone
```

i also made a file /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
And wrote this in it:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{1004}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="root"
```

Still not showing devices.

Comment: http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/09/the-most-comprehensive-write-up-on-how.html

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me: After connecting the USB cable, open the USB options on your device and switch from MTP to PTP.
I still haven't been able to find a way to root my LG G2 (D802) with its Stock Android 5.0.2 Lolipop, as all guides seem to dictate some kind of Windows.
It sucks to have to use Windows to root a Linux device.